# ¿Cómo puedo devolver los registros de una base de datos que tiene 4 tablas a un <select>?

Tags: php, mysql, crud

les comento, lo que pasa es que tengo una base de datos con 4 tablas(funcionario, periódico, clasificación y nota), la tabla **nota** tiene 3 campos foreign key, cada campo tiene relación con una de las tres tablas restantes de la base de datos.

estoy haciendo un **CRUD**, ya inserto y elimino, pero ahora quiero editar el registro, cuando selecciono editar el registro me devuelve los datos que le corresponde a ese **id**, hasta ahí todo bien, pero como uso `<select>` para seleccionar los datos, resulta que a la hora de editar el registro solo me muestra los datos del **id** correspondiente, pero no me muestra las otras opciones que tiene el `<select>`.

ejemplo: quiero editar un registro y cambiarle el tipo de periódico, en mi base de datos tengo 5 tipos de periódicos. obviamente cuando hice un registro pues seleccione uno de los 5 periódicos, pero a la hora de hacer la edición y seleccionar otro periódico, solo me aparece el periódico que seleccione a la hora del registro. y yo quiero que me aparezcan los demás periódicos.

les dejo mi codigo de la hoja de editar registro.

```
<?php

        include("conexion.php");

        $id = $_GET["id"];

        $sql= "SELECT nt.id,peri.name, nt.tipo_nota, func.name_func, clas.name, nt.url, nt.titulo, nt.texto,nt.fecha from nota nt inner join 
                funcionario func on nt.nombre = func.id
                inner join clasificacion clas on nt.clasificacion = clas.id
                inner join periodicos peri on nt.periodico = peri.id where nt.id = $id 
                ";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Seguimiento de medios digitales</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="tabla.php" role="button">Registro</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <form action="actualizar.php" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-lg-6">

                    <?php 
                        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                    ?>

                    <label>Selecione el periodico:</label>
                    <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="periodico">

                    <?php foreach ($resultado as $periodico): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $periodico['id'];?>"><?php echo $periodico['name'];?></option>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les dejo la imagen de mi base de datos.

Saludos y de antemano **AGRADEZCO** sus respuestas.

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes realizar lo siguiente, comentas que solo necesitas seleccionar los periodicos en el select. seria esto

```
 $sql= "select * from periodicos ";
 $resul_periodico = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Tu select quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
 <label>Selecione el periodico:</label>
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="periodico">

                <?php foreach ($resul_periodico as $periodico): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $periodico['id'];?>"><?php echo $periodico['name'];?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, tu respuesta me ayudo a despejar mis dudas. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una consulta específica para traer todos los periódicos amigo:

```
$getNewspaper = "SELECT * FROM periodicos";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $getNewspaper);
```

Y tu SELECT quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="periodico">
    <?php foreach ($resultado as $periodico): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $periodico['id'];?>"><?php echo $periodico['name'];?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php foreach ($query as $item): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $item['id'];?>"><?php echo $item['name'];?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

El primer OPTION es el que cargará en tu SELECT el valor actual del registro que deseas editar. Y el segundo OPTION cargará todos los periódicos que tengas en tu tabla para que puedas seleccionar uno.

Comment: saludos amigo, gracias por el dato, me ha servido mucho para aclarar mis ideas. Saludos! y me ha servido.